# Why does interface builder present my views with some of them greyed out

Tags: ios, xcode, interface-builder

I am working with several view controllers in interface builder and I find the view are represented differently. I am viewing in wR hC mode.
Some of the views have the left hand side greyed out and others use the whole view.
Yet in each case the leading constraints of the views have been set to zero.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Have you set different constraints for different sizes / traits?

Comment: Yes, for each of the size classes

Comment: OK ... is it possible you have mixed something up, so when in wR hC mode, the views on the left hand side are outside the bounds of the superview?

Comment: Don't think so, because when I run it in the simulator (iPhone 7 plus) landscape the views do take up the whole screen.

Comment: In your images... what's the light gray vertical line?

Comment: And... are there additional objects there? Are they completely hidden? Not in the right place? Or is "Set Min" really supposed to be over at the left edge of the gray area?

Comment: set min is really supposed to be at the extreme left border, and appears so in the simulator. There is a hidden text field used in a different size class.

Comment: ok - but... what is the vertical gray line? Is that the left edge of a UIView holding the purple view + slider + white (image view?) + label?

Comment: Sorry Don, I just can't see a vertical grey line - except on the top image - and that's part of my question. Why does it divide up this way?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/142316/discussion-between-donmag-and-steve-harris).

Answer (score 0):

It turns out I had simulated metrics set to "detail" when I should have had "inferred".